# How to use Application.ThreadExit in non-WindowsForms Application?(Multithreaded app, need to check main thread with event)

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

My application needs to know when the main thread ends and I found `Application.ThreadExit` handler. However I can't figure out how to use it. All the examples show `Application.ThreadExit += new EventHandler(AppEvents.OnThreadExit);`. But this is for Windows Forms, My application is a Console Application.
Thank you!

Comment: can you do something before `main` returns?

Comment: I can't touch Main in my case. I'd like to just attach to some kind of thread event handler and get a notification.

Comment: Use the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit event instead.  Not quite the same, you can of course also consider firing your own event.

Comment: There are two nonBackground threads... Main thread stoppes, additional thread is paused... and process still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In console, I always use the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` delegate, with DllImport

After class declaration, use:

```
  private delegate bool ConsoleEventDelegate(int eventType);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventDelegate callback, bool add);
```

And then in program, set the handler:

```
var handler = new ConsoleEventDelegate(ConsoleEventCallback);
             SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, true);

static bool ConsoleEventCallback(int eventType)
{
    if (eventType == 2)
    {
        //Main thread Console is being closed!
       // handle other threads
    }
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That should be a great solution... but i don't understand, where should i declare "var handler"(need to do it in class outside main)

Comment: Wait a minute... This code helps to check, if Console is closed... but i have two threads and need to fire event, when main thread is stopped

Comment: Indeed that what I do on my code. On eventype 2. I check running threads to be canceled before console exits.

Comment: You can declare handler in Main method. When you use setconsolehandler the event is set for app lifetime

Comment: sorry, if you were misunderstood, but additional thread has property IsBackground = false and still works (in pause mode) when main thread terminates... and i need to kill the additional thread just when mainthreadexitevent fires

Comment: And could you tell me, how to fire event number 1000? [Full ctrlhandler class link](https://gist.github.com/bboyle1234/a225218cf4a6825c058c)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code as shown below for console as well :-

```
Application.ThreadExit += new EventHandler(OnThreadExit);
```

which will subscribe the event it means whenever thread will exit it will call `OnThreadExit` method as shown below :-

```
public static void OnThreadExit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        Console.WriteLine("thread is shutting down.");
}
```

Comment: "Application" is underlined and changes color to red.... Which namespace i should use to fix it?